# ng-class is binding to different variable in child scope instead of assigned variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a parent scope and a child scope, each have tags with ng-class="some-class: boolean". The child scope variable is set to 'true' in a click function. The parent is set to 'true' in a .$on function. When the .$on is triggered the variable sets to 'true' as expected, but it does not apply the class name to the tag.

The really weird thing is that when the child scope's variable is set to true it applies the correct class to BOTH elements. The variables are completely different names and so are the classes.

What am I doing wrong?

**Controllers**

```
var app = angular.module('profileApp', []);

    app.controller('ProfileController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.contentVisible = false;
    $scope.$on('animationEnd', function(){
        $scope.contentVisible = true;
    });
}]);

//DIRECTIVES
app.directive('introSection', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'templates/intro-section.html',
    controller: function($scope){
        $('#cityOutline svg').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
            $scope.$emit('animationEnd');
        });
     }
  }
});
app.directive('experienceSection', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/experience-section.html',
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.toggleDetails = false;

            $scope.showDetails = function(){
                $scope.toggleDetails = true;
            };
            $scope.hideDetails = function(){
                $scope.toggleDetails = false;
            };
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="profileApp">
<head>
  <script src="js/lib/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/profileController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ProfileController">
  <header id="nav" ng-class="{'visible': contentVisible}">
  </header>
<experience-section>
  <div id="project-details" ng-class="{'open': toggleDetails}">
    <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="hideDetails()">X</button>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="flat-button" ng-click="showDetails()">View Details</button>
</experience-section>
```

Comment: Element IDs should be unique within the entire document. I see your header tags have the same id.

Comment: Sorry, bad copy paste job. There is only one header. I edited my post

Comment: What is the content of `templates/experience-section.html`? You have html inside `<experience-section>` but don't transclude?

Comment: The content you see inside <experience-section> is pulled from templates/experience-section.html. I just showed the output to simplify it. I edited to show the ng-click that calls "showDetails" for more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok This is a common mistake. In order to know when things inside a scope has changed angular need to run a digest cycle that does the dirty checking of all the content of the scopes and then can inform views that they need to update. (see the official doc on that if you want to know more about it : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Usually, you almost never have to worry about that digest cycle, angular is doing it for you automatically ... as long a you stay in the angular's 'world'. When I say the angular's world I mean one of angular's DOM event binding (like `ng-click`, `ng-change`, `ng-touch` ...) and the `$timeout` service.

In your case, when you do :

```
$('#cityOutline svg').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) { 
         $scope.$emit('animationEnd');
});
```

unfortunately you are not in the angular's world anymore. Meaning that when you emit the "animationEnd" event (even when you emit it with angular's helpers $on and $emit) angular digest cycle is not triggered and angular doesn't know the value has changed so it cannot update the views.

So in your case, the solution is just to call `$scope.$apply();` just after the `$scope.$emit()`. This way you force angular to check if anything has changed. 
So your code would look like that :

```
$('#cityOutline svg').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) { 
         $scope.$emit('animationEnd');
         $scope.$apply();
});
```

So here is what happens with the weird behavior you have when you click the 'close' button :

- the animationEnd event is triggered (obviously by jQuery) ;
- your code updates the value of the scope ;
- angular doesn't detect that change right now because the digest cycle was not called ;
- you click on the close button ;
- your code updates the value of the other scope ;
- now angular is running it's digest cycle ;
- it detects (just now) that the two values have changed ;
- then it tells the views things have changed and they need to update.

So the views only update after the ng-click occurs which is why both classes are applied when you click.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thank you this did it! Thank you for the great explanation it is good to know how the views update and I am sure this will help more in the future

Answer (score 1):

Your changes are not applying when the animation ends. Basically why it works when you click the toggle buttons is that the watches are updating and applying the change to the contentVisibility scope variable. Inside the $on, add a $scope.$apply() at the end, that will add the class correctly when the animation ends.

```
$scope.$on('animationEnd', function(){
    $scope.contentVisible = true;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

here's a plunk. http://plnkr.co/edit/KRbxJiZOJRSvZhaNKTB1?p=preview